# Why do I get repeated information on my query with ProLog?

Tags: prolog

I'm very new to ProLog, butI'm doing a simple blood donation query system, however I don't understand why I get multiple of the same information when I do a query.

For example, when I do `?-pode_doar(ph,A)` I get:

```
A = pa
A = pb
A = pc
A = pd
A = pe
A = pf
A = pf
A = pg
A = pg
A = ph
A = ph
A = ph
A = ph
```

This is the code:

```
doador(pa,h,18,51,a,p).
doador(pb,h,18,51,a,n).
doador(pc,h,18,51,b,p).
doador(pd,h,18,51,b,n).
doador(pe,h,18,51,ab,p).
doador(pf,h,18,51,ab,n).
doador(pg,h,18,51,o,p).
doador(ph,h,18,51,o,n).

tipo_a(A):-
    doador(A,_,_,_,B,_),
    B=a.

tipo_b(A):-
    doador(A,_,_,_,B,_),
    B=b.

tipo_ab(A):-
    doador(A,_,_,_,B,_),
    B=ab.

tipo_o(A):-
    doador(A,_,_,_,B,_),
    B=o.

fator_p(A):-
    doador(A,_,_,_,_,B),
    B=p.

fator_n(A):-
    doador(A,_,_,_,_,B),
    B=n.

apto(A):-
    doador(A,_,B,C,_,_),
    B>=18,
    B=<65,
    C>=50.

pode_doar(A,B):-
    apto(A),
    doador(A,_,_,_,C,D),
    doador(B,_,_,_,E,F),
    (
    (C=E,D=F);
    (C=E,fator_n(A));
    (
    (tipo_o(A),fator_n(A));
    (tipo_o(B),tipo_o(A),D=F)
    );
    (tipo_ab(B),D=F)
    ).
```

For reference: `doador(name,gender,age,weight,blood_type,rh_factor)`

I expected to get all of the eligible people whom A can be a donor to.

Comment: You get as many answers as there are ways to prove those answers; so if there are 3 different ways to prove the same answer, you will get that answer 3 times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes sense. How do I only make one answer possible, or does this behavior not matter?

Comment: There are ways to do it; whether it matters enough to implement them is up to you.

Comment: To prevent backtracking, wrap in https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=once/1 or use cut (exclamation mark) at end.